# android replace view (fragment)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am having trouble with my view. Basically I am using Fragment here are my screen shot.
Photo A
[image: photo A]
Photo B
[image: photo B]

don't mind the tabs. When I click Setting at upper right of Photo A I inflate the `Settings Layout`
then if I click Account Settings the `Settings Layout` replaced by `Account Detail` layout

after that if I want to logout I will click the Setting but my screen still got the 'Account Detail' page which is the photo B but it must be the `Settings Layout`(photo A)

I don't know how to achieve this. below are my codes.

Settings Button :
Fragment fragment => getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    android.R.id.content);           if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
                            } else {

```
            //fragment
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
            editor.putString("user_name", user_name);
            editor.putInt("user_id", user_id);
            editor.commit();

            Fragment mFragment = new SettingsFragment();

            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(android.R.id.content, mFragment, "settings");
            ft.commit();

        }
```

in my Fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
       if (view != null) {
          ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();          //
          System.out.println("asd"+parent);
          if (parent != null) {
        parent.removeView(view);
           }
       } else {

    }
 return view;   
}
```

my Account Setting button :

```
account.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {             @Override           public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment mFragment = new AccountSettings();

                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction();

                ft.replace(R.id.lists, mFragment);

                // ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();            }       });
```

Please spare me I'm new to android.Any suggestion and comment would be great help.  Thanks

Comment: Instead of replace you can use "add" then when you want to go back you can just pop the fragments you want to dismiss

Comment: @Yume117 what is the code for pop?

Comment: Android doc : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Comment: dunno how to do this right, haha

Answer (score 1):

For example :

This'll pop the last fragment transition with this fragment tag

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        int stackSize = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        if (stackSize == 0) {
            finish();
        }
        else {
            String fragmentTag = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(stackSize - 1).getName();
            fragmentManager.popBackStack(fragmentTag, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
```

And this is a way to do transition

```
        @Override   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

                    CustomFragment fragment = new CustomFragment();
                    getActivity()
                       .getSupportFragmentManager()
                       .beginTransaction()
                       .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.anim_back_right,R.animator.anim_back_left, R.animator.anim_left, R.animator.anim_right)
                       .add(R.id.custom_fragment, fragment)
                       .addToBackStack(MainActivity.THIS_FRAGMENT_TAG)
                       .commit();
        }
```

The idea is here

Comment: Try to do it step by step. Valid bit by bit so you don't loose it ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
       if (view != null) {
          ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();          //
          System.out.println("asd"+parent);
          if (parent != null) {
        parent.removeView(view);
           }
       } else {

    }
 return view;   
}
```

change to

```
Fragment mFragment = new Settings();
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            System.out.println(view);
            if (view != null) {

                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                // System.out.println("asd"+parent);
                if (parent != null) {
                    parent.removeView(view);

                } else {
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();
                    ft.detach(mFragment);
                    ft.attach(mFragment);
                    ft.replace(R.id.lists, mFragment);
                    ft.commit();
                    //System.out.println("saadasd");
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selectionfrag, container,
                            false);

                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.lists, mFragment);
                    ft.commit();
                } catch (InflateException e) {

                }
            }

            return view;
        }
```

I just detach the fragment and attach it then replace content.

```
ft.detach(mFragment);
ft.attach(mFragment);
ft.replace(R.id.lists, mFragment);
```

but I don't know if this is the best practice. could anyone tell?